# Passing Variables to Django Comment Views

Tags: python, django, django-comments

Alright, I know I've asked similar questions, but I feel this is hopefully a bit different. I'm integrating django.comments into my application, and the more I play with it, the more I realize it may not even be worth my while at the end of the day. That aside, I've managed to add Captcha to my comments, and I've learned that customizing the form is a terrible idea (hiding that honeypot is stupidly difficult, and from what I can tell requires JS to hide. Pity.). That's alright though, I've managed to work with it. However, the templates for the comments (preview and posted) are frustrating.

When a user is sent to the preview or posted templates, I'd like my sidebar's that have dynamic data to still be functional, however they're not. Do I have to override/rewrite the comments views to push data to these views? At that point it seems like I'm rewriting a major chunk of the comment system anyway, and it'd almost be beneficial to just write my own in that case. I'm more than willing to do that, and totally understand that I'm not entitled to a perfect comments system from Django. I just want to make sure I'm thinking right, and that if I want more than what I get from the comment views, that rewriting them is my only path.

Surely someone's found a healthier way though, so I thought I'd poll the audience. Any thoughts? If you need more info, just lemme know!

Comment: -1. This looks more like a rant than a question.

Comment: -1: "I'm not entitled to a perfect comments system from Django".  Doesn't sound like a question to me, either.  Pity.

Comment: You guys took this the completely wrong way. Not mad at django or their comment system. Was merely looking for guidance. Sorry for the way it apparently came off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic data in sidebars is what template tags are for.

There's absolutely no need to muck around with the built-in views - just define the tags add them to your templates.

Answer (score 0):

I user template tags as well. Templates in Django are truly for displaying data only.
I think Django believes in separation between the Designers and the Developers. So, they are enforcing the idea of templates should be simple enough for web designer to work with. (the photoshop guys)

So, as long as you don't need complected functionality, just pass the info to a filter and have it do the data manipulation and return the final string that you need.